# jQuery: Double Parent Selection

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to navigate through Divs using parent, child relations. The following code works... But I'm looking for a proper way to do it.
Let me know if there's an easier way:

jQuery selector:

```
$(this).parent().parent().children(".edit-box")
```

Called in the $('.edit').click function:

```
$('.edit').click(function (e) {
            console.log($(this).parent().parent().children(".edit-box"))
            if ($(this).parent().parent().children(".edit-box").is(":hidden")){
                console.log('test')
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '-66px 0', width: '55px'})
                    .parents('.widget');
                $(this).parent().parent().children(".edit-box").show();
            } else {
                $(this).css({backgroundPosition: '', width: '24px'})
                    .parents('.widget');
                $(this).parent().parent().children(".edit-box").hide();
            }
            e.preventDefault();
        });
```

HTML:

```
<li class="widget color-black" id="network_map">
   <div class="widget-head" style="cursor: move;">
      <a href="#" class="collapse">COLLAPSE</a>
      <h3>Network Map</h3>
      <a href="#" class="remove">CLOSE</a><a href="#" class="edit">EDIT</a>
   </div>
   <div class="edit-box" style="display:none;">
      <ul>
         <li class="item"><label>Change the title?</label><input value="Network Map"></li>
      </ul>
<li class="item"><label>Available colors:</label><ul class="colors"><li class="color-yellow"></li><li class="color-red"></li><li class="color-blue"></li><li class="color-orange"></li><li class="color-green"></li><li class="color-black"></li></ul></li></div>
<div class="widget-content"><img src="assets/img/NetworkMap.PNG"></div>
</li>
```

PLEASE NOTE:
There is more than one widget with more than one ".edit-box"

Comment: What is `$(this)` at `$(this).parent().parent().children(".edit-box")` ?

Comment: @Pachonk where do you call this: `$(this).parent().parent().children(".edit-box")`

Comment: Wow, that was idiotic of me...
I added the surrounding source. Thanks for the clarifications @erkaner

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is your friend here `$(this).closest('#network_map')`

Comment: I have multiple widgets, so that won't be suitable. Widgets are also loaded dynamically.